# Is there a method can be used to modify particular document in Firestore when user click on a card?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Good morning everyone. I have a question here, is there a way that can be used to modify one document in the 'users' collection when the user clicks on a card inside the Android app? I tried to use the code below, but it seems that it doesn't make sense.

My idea is when the user clicks on 1 event, it shows the detail of the event and there is 1 button to click so that the eventID can store in the current user's document. Can anyone here answer my question? Thank you.

[image: DB Structure]

//When particular event card is click:

```
    joinBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            CollectionReference collRef= rootRef.collection("users");

            //the eventDocID is saved in user's "save_event".

            collRef.document().update("saved_event", a.eventDocId).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<Void> task) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "onComplete");
                }
            });
        }
    });`
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact document you want to update.

Comment: @AlexMamo I updated just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to perform an update, you need to specify the ID of the document you want to update. So you have to pass "pJbM8gfwHiuJUP8R4320" to the document() method and call update() like this:

```
Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
update.put("eventDocId", "newID");
DocumentReference docId = collRef.document("pJbM8gfwHiuJUP8R4320");
docId.update("saved_event", update).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<Void> task) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Update complete.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a listener to every card like so:

```java
// create a CardView and assign a value.
CardView card_view = (CardView) findViewById(id); 

card_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do whatever you want here
        }
    });
```

or you can use a callback:
 `android:onClick="@{(view) -> callback.onCategoryClick(view, viewModel)}"`

I also suggest looking into data-binding: [**Documentation**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#java)