# Firestore returning null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: DB strucuture]The application keeps returning to MainActivity when I try to access the "EventDetail" activity. This happen when I added joinBtn.setOnClickListener and amend it according to the previous posts according to suggestion given: [Is there a method can be used to modify particular document in Firestore when user click on a card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68931815/is-there-a-method-can-be-used-to-modify-particular-document-in-firestore-when-us/)

Can anyone here help me to resolve this issue? Thank you in advance.

```
public class EventDetail extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "DetailActivity";

    EventModel event;

    private TextView textViewEName, textViewEVenue, textViewEDate, textViewEDesc;
    private Button joinBtn;

    private FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private FirebaseAuth fAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_detail);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Started.");

        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


        textViewEName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textEventNameDetail);
        textViewEDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textEventDateDetail);
        textViewEVenue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textEventVenueDetail);
        textViewEDesc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textEventDescDetail);
        joinBtn=findViewById(R.id.joinBtn);

        textViewEName.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("eventName").toString());
        textViewEDate.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("eventDate").toString());
        textViewEVenue.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("eventVenue").toString());
        textViewEDesc.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("eventDesc").toString());


        //When particular event card is click
        joinBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //Make addEvent object 'a' to access variable in addEvent
            AddEvent a = new AddEvent();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                CollectionReference collRef= rootRef.collection("users");

                Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
                update.put("eventDocId", a.eventDocId);
  
                DocumentReference docId = collRef.document(user.getUid());
                docId.update("saved_event", update).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Update complete.");
                    }
                });
                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The error appear after I add this block of code.

```
joinBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //Make addEvent object 'a' to access variable in addEvent
            AddEvent a = new AddEvent();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                CollectionReference collRef= rootRef.collection("users");

                Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
                update.put("eventDocId", a.eventDocId);
  
                DocumentReference docId = collRef.document(user.getUid());
                docId.update("saved_event", update).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Update complete.");
                    }
                });
                
            }
        });
```

When I check logcat, it appear this error:

> 2021-08-27 08:24:40.590 18531-18531/com.example.myvolunteer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.myvolunteer, PID: 18531
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myvolunteer/com.example.myvolunteer.EventDetail}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.collection(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.collection(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
> at com.example.myvolunteer.AddEvent.(AddEvent.java:40)
> at com.example.myvolunteer.EventDetail$1.(EventDetail.java:63)
> at com.example.myvolunteer.EventDetail.onCreate(EventDetail.java:61)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8198)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8182)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3765)

Comment: I think the document you are trying to update don't exists in Firestore database.

Comment: in `onComplete` did you added `if` statement like this: `if(task.isSuccesfull)` then do your stuff on success and on failed.

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal Please refer to the db structure picture that I have attached.

Comment: @VishalBeep I try it just now, but still the same.

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting NullPointerException?

Comment: @AlexMamo The block of code that cause the problem is already added on the posts.

Comment: Which line in particular?

Comment: Can you show the code of saving the data in Firestore, I think the document Id and the User Ids are not matching, that's why the document is null.

Comment: CollectionReference collRef= rootRef.collection("users");

Comment: The error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method` `com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.collection(java.lang.String) on a null object reference` highlights that the rootRef is null which implies that the `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()` used inside the AddEvent is not being initialized correctly. Can you show what is being done inside the AddEvent class? Also can you remove the AddEvent object and use a known value for the update method: `update.put(‘eventDocId’, ‘known_value’)` and see if it is working?

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code**

```
 docId.update("saved_event", update).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                      Log.d(TAG, "Update complete.");
                    else
                      Log.d(TAG, "Something went wrong : "+task.getException());
                }
            });
```

Comment: The problem still exists